# Installation Failure in python

Tags: python

I had a problem trying to install TensorFlow. After multiple unsuccessful attempts, I uninstalled everything related to python.

Now, when I try to install python with

```
pip install python
```

I got the following error related to the path:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fffa1d233c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can't install Python via pip, because you may have deleted pip together with Python. Try to install Python from the official Python website: https://www.python.org/downloads/